# Why does the expectation not increase?

Tags: probability

Alex takes a quiz with $4n$ multiple choice problems, each problem has $4$ choices. If he makes random guesses, the expectation is $n$ correct. I am wondering if the expectation remains unchanged if Alex is told

Statement 1: there are equal number of correct A,B,C and D answers.

Statement 2: there are more As than Bs in the solution manual.

For S1, I checked $n=1$ and the expectation is $1$ if Alex guesses $ABCD$ ($1$ case with 4 correct answers; $6$ cases with $2$ correct; $8$ cases with $1$ correct and $9$ cases with $0$ correct).

For S2, I also checked $n=1$ and the expectation is $1$ if he guesses $AAAA$. There are totally $93$ cases with more As than Bs: $1$ case with $4$ correct; $12$ cases with $3$ correct; $48$ cases with $2$ correct and $32$ cases with $1$ correct.

My question is, is it generally true that S1 and S2 have no positive effect on making correct guesses? What is the intuitive meaning of that?

Comment: Statement 1 is useless. Statement 2 could be helpful to Alex if he uses it wisely. For example, if he first makes random guesses (uniform distribution over A, B, C, D), then erases all the B answers and changes them to A. By the way, your way of figuring the expectation is wrong. You seem to be assuming that the quiz is randomized. There is no reason to believe that the quiz answers have been randomized; the randomness is created when Alex randomizes his guesses.

Comment: @bof Why is S1 useless? For S2, what is the correct probability space associated with it? Thanks for your comment!